# how to check if Mongo DBCollection#drop() has finished using the java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I have millions of documents in a MongoDB collection.  These get created during testing and I wish to remove them all when running unit tests.  DBCollection#remove(new BasicDBObject()); takes forever and a day,  I have honestly no idea how long the remove takes (any hints would be great) but it's much longer than I've been prepared to wait so far.

So I'm trying to use DBCollection#drop(); instead  Unfortunately, this runs in the background and there appears to be no way of making it block.  This is using the latest java driver.

How can I drop() a Mongo collection and either
a) make it run in the foreground or
b) check to see if it's finished before passing control onto other tests

*eta*
I have 95 million documents at the moment, this will not be an uncommon amount for me to drop.

Comment: As per I know, `drop()` is blocking and the operation will be completed in moments (`drop()` is very fast because data files are not loaded into memory for this operation). Whole disk space is freed to OS which is not the case with `remove()`.

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe I'm doing something else post-drop then.  It's certainly not releasing the disk space though.

Comment: This is not true. On dropping a database or repairing a database, the disk space will always be freed. Check Eliot's comment `https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2838` about this, if you want to be sure.

Comment: This is dropping collections.  I just used the "show dbs" on the mongo command line. It shows both my databases (one is gridfs) using over 30gb each when they contained no documents in their collections.  "df" in bash showed no difference pre or post drop();

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood and confused between dropping collection and database. In collection drop, space won't be released. Sorry.

Comment: No problem.  Elliot -> "The only time mongo releases disk space is when you drop a database or do a repair."  It's not supposed to free disk space.  My fault for having a mac with a tiny hard drive.

Comment: I've been following a pattern of creating a new database per JUnit test case (i.e. class) and a new collection per test (i.e. method).  I drop the collection at the end of the method (on tear down) and database at the end of the test case.  I appreciate this might not be possible in your framework (especially if testing production-like settings) but it solves this problem in my case.